# DatetimeIndex: what is the purpose of 'freq' attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I miss the point of the 'freq' attribute in a pandas DatatimeIndex object. It can be passed at construction time or set at any time as a property but I don't see any difference in the behaviour of the DatatimeIndex object when this property changes.

Plase look at this example. We add 1 day to a DatetimeIndex that has freq='B' but the returned index contains non-business days:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

rng = pd.date_range('2012-01-05', '2012-01-10', freq=BDay())
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(rng)
print(index)

index2 = index + pd.Timedelta('1D')
print(index2)
```

This is the output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-05', '2012-01-06', '2012-01-09', '2012-01-10'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')

DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-06', '2012-01-07', '2012-01-10', '2012-01-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

- Why isn't freq considered when performing computation (+/- Timedelta) on the DatetimeIndex?
- Why freq doesn't reflect the actual data contained in the DatetimeIndex? ( it says 'B' even though it contains non-business days)

Comment: I have the impression that `freq` is used [to inform optimisations on the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#indexing); it's not a validator. Thus, it takes a cue from the initial `date_range()` call to make an informed guess as to what optimisations might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.shift.html)

```
index.shift(1)
Out[336]: DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-06', '2012-01-09', '2012-01-10', '2012-01-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Also BDay will do that too

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
index + BDay(1)
Out[340]: DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-06', '2012-01-09', '2012-01-10', '2012-01-11'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Comment: @luca why you say , does not use it , it pass to shift , as i show above

Answer (score 0):

From [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19172) issue:

> The freq attribute is meant to be purely descriptive, so it doesn't
>   and shouldn't impact calculations. Potentially docs could be clearer.