# What is the impact of having freq=None instead of a specific value as a DatetimeIndex attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

These 2 ways of creating a date column and setting it as the index of the dataframe have *almost* the same result, except that the `freq` attribute of the index is `None` in the first case and `M` in the second one:

```python
# This sets the index frequency to None
df["Date"] = pd.date_range("1864-jan", periods=df.shape[0], freq="M")
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

# This sets the index frequency to M
df.set_index(pd.date_range("1864-jan", periods=df.shape[0], freq="M"), inplace=True)
df.index.name = "Date"
```

1. I assume this is because in the first case we first create a *column* and the freq attribute provided in the `date_range` function is lost in the `set_index` operation. Is this correct?
2. What is the impact/consequence of an index that has no `freq` defined? Are some operations dependent on this attribute and hence going to fail?

Comment: related: [DatetimeIndex: what is the purpose of 'freq' attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48192168/10197418) - not sure if this changed by now, but in 2018, [freq was only a descriptive attribute](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19172#issuecomment-356682665).

Comment: IMO you loose `freq` when assigning `DatetimeIndex` to a column of `DataFrame`. At this step it becomes `Series` which has no `freq` attribute.